# Migrate tslint to @angular-eslint/schematics: ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree: @angular/compiler@12.1.2

Tags: angular, npm, typescript-eslint, angular-eslint

I'm trying to migrate tslint to eslint in my angular 11 library using the official documentation [here](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#migrating-an-angular-cli-project-from-codelyzer-and-tslint).

When I run the cmd `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@4.3.0` I'm getting the following error:

```
✖ Package installation failed: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@12.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics/node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@">= 12.0.0 < 13.0.0" from @angular-eslint/template-parser@12.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics/node_modules/@angular-eslint/template-parser
npm ERR!     peer @angular-eslint/template-parser@"*" from @angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template@4.3.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics/node_modules/@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template
npm ERR!       @angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template@"4.3.0" from @angular-eslint/schematics@4.3.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@">= 11.2.0 < 12.0.0" from @angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template@4.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics/node_modules/@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template
npm ERR!   @angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template@"4.3.0" from @angular-eslint/schematics@4.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics
npm ERR!     dev @angular-eslint/schematics@"4.3.0" from the root project
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out [here](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/532#issuecomment-856065153) that you just need to run the following command:

```
npm i -D @angular-eslint/template-parser@4
```

And then you can run:

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@4.3.0
```